# Gradient Descent Implementation in Python returns Nan

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, statistics

I am trying to implement gradient descent in python; the implementation works when I try it with training_set1 but it returns not a number(nan) when I try it training_set. Any idea why my code is broken?

```
from collections import namedtuple

TrainingInstance = namedtuple("TrainingInstance", ['X', 'Y'])

training_set1 = [TrainingInstance(0, 4), TrainingInstance(1, 7),
    TrainingInstance(2, 7), TrainingInstance(3, 8),
    TrainingInstance(8, 12)]


training_set = [TrainingInstance(60, 3.1), TrainingInstance(61, 3.6),
    TrainingInstance(62, 3.8), TrainingInstance(63, 4),
    TrainingInstance(65, 4.1)]

def grad_desc(x, x1): 
    # minimize a cost function of two variables using gradient descent
    training_rate = 0.1
    iterations = 5000
    #while sqrd_error(x, x1) > 0.0000001:
    while iterations > 0:
        #print sqrd_error(x, x1)
        x, x1 = x - (training_rate * deriv(x, x1)), x1 - (training_rate * deriv1(x, x1))
        iterations -= 1
    return x, x1

def sqrd_error(x, x1):
    sum = 0.0
    for inst in training_set:
        sum += ((x + x1 * inst.X) - inst.Y)**2
    return sum / (2.0 * len(training_set))

def deriv(x, x1):
    sum = 0.0
    for inst in training_set:
        sum += ((x + x1 * inst.X) - inst.Y)
    return sum / len(training_set)

def deriv1(x, x1):
    sum = 0.0
    for inst in training_set:
        sum += ((x + x1 * inst.X) - inst.Y) * inst.X
    return sum / len(training_set)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print grad_desc(2, 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Reduce `training_rate` so that the objective decreases at each iteration.

See Figure 6. in this paper: http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/lecun-98b.pdf